# My own signed APK now warning of "unrecognised developer" when installing locally

Tags: installation, apk

This warning has started showing up literally in the last day or so, whereas previously my own APK (signed with a keystore/password that I have successfully used on currently released software) would just install locally without fuss.

I'm now being told that the play store doesn't recognise my account and requires me to click "continue to install anyway" in order to install it.

What has changed over the last few days?

EDIT: I suspect it is something that's changed in the play store, instead of something I've done, because I went back and tried installing from some previous APKs I built and deployed without incident a few days ago, and they are also showing the same error.

Comment: Signing involves a certificate - could your certificate have timed out?

Comment: No the certificate expires in 2038

Comment: May be this is a message from Google Play Protect - it also checks side-loaded apps.

Comment: Weirdly, it's gone away now. I think perhaps my account wasn't being recognised as active or something. I've since logged in and a day later my installs are fine again.